# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted in the virtual environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to make a python virtualenvironment using `virtualenv` in 
I type `virtuelenv env --python=python3` 
I get an error

`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/d/venv/bin/python3'`

So I used the command with `sudo` and therefore type `sudo virtualenv env --python=python3`

The command works this time, now I activate the environment and try to install something using pip, I get

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

I know for a fact that if use `pip` with sudo, it will install packages for the global site packages and no the site packages of the virtual environment. I want to install things to the virtual environment.

I am running ubuntu bionic on WSL, I used to run ubuntu xenial and didn't face this problem.

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the fact you are running in a WSL environment.

Some report this behavior when running on Linux,
but in a folder that is mounted to a "FAT32" partition -
see [Chris Lope](https://www.blogger.com/profile/07800874561061105839)'s blog-post:
[**permissionerror: [errno 1] operation not permitted**](http://www.theeclipse.org/2018/11/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not.html)

I have experienced this behavior while running in an **Ubuntu VM**
in a folder that was **mounted to the host-OS (Windows-NTFS)** as type 'vboxsf'.